# Structured Streaming exception: Append output mode not supported for streaming aggregations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting the following error when I run my spark job:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets;;

I am not sure if the issue is being caused due to lack of a [watermark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking),which I don't know how to apply in this context.
Following is the aggregation operation applied:

```
def aggregateByValue(): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn("Value", expr("(BookingClass, Value)"))
    .groupBy("AirlineCode", "Origin", "Destination", "PoS", "TravelDate", "StartSaleDate", "EndSaleDate", "avsFlag")
    .agg(collect_list("Value").as("ValueSeq"))
    .drop("Value")
}
```

Usage:

```
val theGroupedDF = theDF
  .multiplyYieldByHundred
  .explodeDates
  .aggregateByValue

val query = theGroupedDF.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the `outputMode` to `complete` solved the issue.

```
val query = theGroupedDF.writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this would solve the problem:

```
  val theGroupedDF = theDF
  .multiplyYieldByHundred
  .explodeDates
  .aggregateByValue
  //code bellow
  .withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp())
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
```