# run SQL queries on record history (aggregation) spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a schema -

```
 |-- record_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Data1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Data2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Data3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I want to know the record for each record id with latest timestamp. I have not been able to do this in [structured streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933606/spark-streaming-select-record-with-max-timestamp-for-each-id-in-dataframe-pysp). In Spark Streaming, I have achieved this on each incoming batch by using foreachRDD, and converting each incoming RDD to a dataframe and then running my sql query on it.

However, this yields results only on each new RDD, and not using the whole history. I know I can do this in Spark Streaming using Key Value Pairs, but I'm rather interested in running SQL queries on whole of the History (group by, joins and such). How can I do it in Spark Streaming, and not in Spark Structured Streaming ?
Another reason I cant do this in structured streaming is [because](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#support-matrix-for-joins-in-streaming-queries) I cant use Streaming Aggregation before Joins, which is kind of what I require for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933606/spark-streaming-select-record-with-max-timestamp-for-each-id-in-dataframe-pysp).

Comment: can you use Window functions in streaming ?

Comment: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets.